# ESS and RScript : Executing in style of `compile-dwim-run'

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I just got ESS set up in EMACS (I'm a relative newbie in this area).  I have figured out how to take an R script and fire up an interactive R shell and evaluate a whole buffer ("C-c C-b").  But I'd also like to have the ability to submit an R script via RScript in the way that you can with Perl or Python with `compile-dwim-run', which I have bound to "C-c r", and have the whole output returned to me in a separate buffer without keeping open an interactive R shell.

I can't seem to find a default way to do this, and I'd like to leverage whatever ESS has to work that (I assume there is) before I go off and attempt to roll my own.

Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-c C-l</kbd>  is what you are looking for? Use  <kbd>C-c C-h</kbd>  to see all the keys that are bound on C-c map (an even better approach is to install [helm-descrbind](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds) from emacs package manager - you will be pleasantly surprised :).

[edit:] Sorry, misread your post slightly. You want batch evaluation. That is not available for R. The reason, the analysis in R is usually a complex process which you don't want to execute again and again. So you keep your interactive session open and iteratively achieve what you want.

There have been talks inside ESS to add some batch functionality, but it seems like very few people really need that.

Comment: Thank you!  I may just roll my own... sometimes I just want to eval it for the graphs I produce.  I can do this via interactive R and then shut down, so that may be sufficient for me.

Comment: @mpetis But why would you shut down? Cannot you just reuse the existing session again and again?